# retrieve selected value in row using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I've a table with multiple rows, each row has a drop down list. I am new to javascript and is unable to retrieve the selected value from the row. Any idea how can it be done? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
function chng_page(serialNum, rowid)
{
    alert(rowid);
    alert(serialNum);
    var select_index = document.getElementById('orderStatus').selectedIndex; 
    //get the value of selected option
    var option_value = document.getElementById('orderStatus').options[select_index].value;

    //redirect with value as a url parameter
    window.location = 'orderStatus.php?serialNum=' + serialNum + '&status=' + option_value;
}
</script>
```

//code for drop down list

```
<select id="orderStatus" name="orderStatus" onchange="chng_page(<?php echo $serialNum?    >, this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)">
   <option value="Pending" <?php echo ($status == "Pending") ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Pending</option>
   <option value="Cooking" <?php echo ($status == "Cooking") ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Cooking</option>
   <option value="On The Way" <?php echo ($status == "On The Way") ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>On The Way</option>
   <option value="Delivered" <?php echo ($status == "Delivered") ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Delivered</option>   
</select>
```

Comment: Protip: When adding code to a question, highlight it and click the `{}` in the toolbar, or press `Ctrl`+`K`.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? The above code looks fine to me.

Comment: i can only retrieve the value of the drop down list in the first row (of the table). I'm supposed to retrieve the value from any rows, not only the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention if the select element in each row has a unique id or not, but it somehow shows in your code that they do. 
In that case, you can use JQuery (a popular JavaScript framework) to retrieve the selected value. 
Assuming you have included the JQuery file in your HTML, and attached an event handler to the select element (to make it easier, pass in the id of the current select element as a parameter in the function), do this:

```
var selected_value = $("#id_of_select_element option:selected").val();
```

If the ids of the select elements are unique, that single line of code will definitely work.

Comment: You can avoid JQuery; however, I'm not sure why you would want to do that. It's stable, functional, and supported by all major browsers, IDEs, companies, etc. To include JQuery in your html, google JQuery, or go straight here <a href="http://jquery.com/">http://jquery.com/</a>. Although I recommend you understand JavaScript as much as you can, you'll find yourself using JQuery time and again.

Comment: thank you for the advice! :) reason for not using JQuery is because there are some functions that are clashing with one another like coda slider, pop up, etc

Comment: You have some functions that will clash with JQuery? It shouldn't be so; however, JQuery's objects can be extended (modified) to ensure that the pre-defined JQuery functions do not clash with other libraries. To give you a better advice, one'll have to understand more about your application. Try JQuery to see if it fixes your immediate problem. I can give you a non-JQuery version, but it'll be longer than JQuery (which is why it's used where possible).

Comment: If it works, as I believe it should; consider accepting my answer. Thanks.

Comment: `document.getElementById('elementId').value` also gives the value of the selected <option>

Answer (score 0):

You have the same name/id for the drop down in all table rows

Answer (score 0):

If there is a dropdownlist in each row with same id-> #orderStatus, you should try this,

```
function chng_page(serialNum, ddlist)
{
    var rowid = ddlist.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex
    alert(rowid);
    alert(serialNum);
    var select_index = ddlist.selectedIndex; 
    //get the value of selected option
    var option_value = ddlist.options[select_index].value;

    //redirect with value as a url parameter
    window.location = 'orderStatus.php?serialNum=' + serialNum + '&status=' + option_value;
}

<select name="orderStatus" onchange="chng_page(<?php echo $serialNum?>, this)">
   <option value="Pending" <?php echo ($status == "Pending") ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Pending</option>
   <option value="Cooking" <?php echo ($status == "Cooking") ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Cooking</option>
   <option value="On The Way" <?php echo ($status == "On The Way") ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>On The Way</option>
   <option value="Delivered" <?php echo ($status == "Delivered") ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Delivered</option>   
</select>
```